# Extracting Campaign details with Email and SMS Tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, sms, tracking

I'm looking for a way to associate an email or sms send with a campaign and then when I extract the tracking data I want to have that same identifier in the data. Essentially, I am looking for a way to pull data out of marketing cloud to put in CRM for my agents to see what emails/sms were sent to each person and what campaign that email/sms was a part of. Has anyone found a clean way to add that data to the message and then export it with the other email tracking info? Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at using a send log and extract that Info?

Comment: That is an option for email but then we have to add the code to capture that in every email we send. It also does not solve for sms.

Comment: there is an sms send log also, and would have to define what campaign each email was, you could do this in additional attribute for each eamil